# SharePoint custom list view does not displaying items when browser language changes

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

There is a list with column indexed and has values from Term store.

A user has created a list view in french locale, list view filter contains French key words in it. But when user access same list view using English Locale, Filters doesn't work and their is no results shown.

How to handle two locale strings?

Thanks in advance. Really appreciated your help :)

Vinay Prasad B S

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming in code equal condition is not working well. When user change locale these conditions change.

Share sample code so that answer can be more precise.

Comment: Hi Subodh, I haven't written any code. This issue is coming from List View Filters.